# Can I call $(document).ready() to re-activate all on load event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

Does anyone happen to know IF and HOW I could re-call all on-load event handlers? I'm referencing some .js files that I DON'T have control over, and these .js libraries do their initialization in $(document).ready(), and unfortunately don't provide any easy function to re-initialize.

I'm currently trying to replace a large div block with content from an ajax call, and so I have to re-initialize the external libraries. So, it would be nice just to call $(document).ready() in order to re-initialize EVERYTHING.

So far, I've tried this on the ajax call:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert('1'); // Displays '1'
    $('#content').html(data);
    alert('2'); // Displays '2'
    $(document).ready();
    alert('3'); // Does not display
}
```

Calling `$(document).ready();` fails quietly too. JavaScript console shows no errors. Does anyone know if this is possible (without modifying javascript library files)?

Comment: Oh, `$(document).ready()` _registers functions to be called when the document is ready_.  Calling it with no parameters seems wrong.  It should have a function to register.  If you saw it "fail silently" probably all that happened is it said "oh okay no function to register, I'm just going to bail...."

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since you asked how to do it without modifying the external JS files, I'll answer that way.  I've traced through the `.ready()` function in jQuery in the debugger and it appears that the root function that gets called when the page is ready is this:

```
jQuery.ready();
```

But, it appears you cannot just call it again to accomplish what you want because it appears that when it fires the first time, it unbinds from the functions that were previously registered (e.g. forgetting them).  As such, calling `jQuery.ready()` manually a second time does not retrigger the same function calls again and I verified that in the debugger (breakpoint was only hit once, not second time).

So, it appears that you cannot solve this problem without either changing the jQuery implementation so it doesn't unbind (to allow multiple firings) or changing each piece of ready handler code to use your own events that you can fire as many times as you want.

Comment: I just went trough jQuery's sources, and it is correct what you have concluded with.

Comment: Also, editing the jQuery's ready-function seems dangerous as it might be called several times during load.

Comment: @Alxandr - I agree that modifying the source would probably not be the best way to do it though it is probably the only way without modifying the external JS files as the OP asked.  The safe way would be to put everything on your own event, trigger that event yourself from the normal ready function and then trigger it manually later (as you have suggested Alxandr).

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks! This is the actual answer to the question, thank you. It's unfortunate that it unbinds the handlers after the load, but I guess it makes sense from the design perspective of what ready() is actually supposed to be used for.

Comment: One wild thought that I haven't investigated fully investigated would be to patch jQuery to save the current implementation of $(document).ready function into your own variable, then replace the $(document).ready function with your own function that turns each of those calls into your own custom event registration and then register one occurrence of the original ready function from which you trigger the custom events.  It's probably doable.

Comment: I "solved" the problem though. Take a look at my revised answer.

Comment: @Alxandr - cool that's an implementation of the idea I wrote about for replacing the existing ready function.  Looks like you made it work.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yeah, but I was working on that years before you wrote your comment xD. I read your comment after I was finnished... Well, you know what they say, great mind thinks alike.

Comment: @Alxandr - it would be best if you could modify it to use the oldReady function rather than invent your own.

Comment: That's great answer. Spent two hours trying to fix my javascripts after adding pjax :) You approach works for me with one small addition: I wrap my functions into one big and call it twice - after page ready and after pjax.

Answer (score 37):

I did something like:

```
// When document is ready...
$(function(){
    onPageLoad();
});

function onPageLoad(){
  // All commands here
}
```

Now I can call this function anytime I need.

Comment: This is by far the best solution here. And what I would've done had I thaught of it earlier

Comment: You would have to be in control of the contents of onPageLoad, which is begging the question. The original problem is that the document ready event itself needs to be fired again. In this example, subsequent calls are made to onPageLoad. If a plugin is already binding to document ready and you're not able to modify that plugin, this method won't do it.

Comment: although this is not the answer to this question i indeed was looking for this +1

Comment: You can discard the anonymous function: `$(onPageLoad);`

Comment: Very simple and elegant solution.

Comment: I use inline events in my html code (onclick,oncomplete, etc) to trigger some "named" js functions, which had been causing my document.ready status to be forgotten. Now at the end of each "named" function, I will call onPageLoad() to refresh and access these anon functions.  Just tested and works great. Thank for  help with my "mixture" of event handlers.

Answer (score 12):

A simple way to achieve this is just to invent your own event like this:

```
$(document).bind('_page_ready', function() { /* do your stuff here */});
```

Then add this:

```
$(function() { $(document).fire('_page_ready'); }); // shorthand for document.ready
```

And last, whenever you need to run it again you simply call this:

```
$(document).fire('_page_ready');
```

#### [Edit]

If you really can't edit the external script-files I've made a jsFiddle that makes what you want to do possible, you can take a look at the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/5dRxh/

However, if you wan't to use this, it's important that you add this script RIGHT AFTER you include jQuery, like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    //script from jsFiddle (only the plugin part at the top).
</script>
<!-- All the other script-files you want to include. -->
```

Comment: Thanks, but like I mentioned to @karim, these are external .js files that I don't have control of, and these .js files basically define their functionality in $(document).ready(), and I can't change that

Comment: @Mike: Then take up a new project, or request better requirements from your higher-ups.

Comment: +1 for figuring out how to replace the existing ready() function with your own, but I don't like that you aren't still using the old jQuery ready function to trigger yours, but have instead made your own ready function.  That seems like you may be losing functionality jQuery has carefully shaken out over the years.

Comment: If you read the source of the jQuery ready-function you'd figure out why. Making them play nice together would have been.... to much work xD.

Comment: Oh, and btw, the one I wrote is more or less exactly the same, as it uses the built in jQuery event system.

Answer (score 9):

You can trigger document.ready second time if you change entire body content:

```
$('body').html($('body').html())
```

Comment: This is perfect! Not sure about browsers but Chrome works as you say! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that this can be done since jquery unbinds the ready event after it is executed. From the source:

```
// Trigger any bound ready events
if ( jQuery.fn.trigger ) {
    jQuery( document ).trigger( "ready" ).unbind( "ready" );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this simple.

Make a function:

```
function REinit() {
        /// PLACE HERE ALL YOUR DOC.READY SCRIPTS
}
```

Place just the Reinit() function inside doc.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    REinit();
});
```

then after an ajax action just call

```
REinit();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is straight forward to just change the ready event to pjax success

Change it from:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // page load stuff
});
```

To:

```
$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {
    // will fire on initial page load, and subsequent PJAX page loads
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be what you want, just hold the ready event until you are really ready.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/

Answer (score 0):

Or, try this:

```
jQuery.extend ({

    document_ready: function (value) {
        $(document).ready (value);
        $(document).ajaxComplete (value);
    }/* document_ready */

});
```

And instead of defining a function by saying:

```
$(document).ready (function () { blah blah blah });
```

say:

```
jQuery.document_ready (function () { blah blah blah });
```

Explanation:

Any function loaded to "document_ready" will be automatically loaded into both "$(document).ready ()" and "$(document).ajaxComplete ()" and will fire under both circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the problem that my `ajax` code *only* worked if it gets called by the `$(document).ready(function(){});` and not in a regular function, so I couldn't wrap it.
 The code was about loading a part of my page and because of some *loading errors* I wanted it to be called again after a `timeout`.

I found out that the code doesn't have to be *in* the `$(document).ready(function(){});` but can be run by it and can also be **called by itself**.

So after I read many solutions from different pages now I've got this code mixed together:

---

```
$(document).ready(loadStuff);
```

---

```
function loadStuff(){   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "path/to/ajax.php",
        data: { some: data, action: "setContent"},
        timeout: 1000, //only one second, for a short loading time
        error: function(){ 
            console.log("An error occured. The div will reload.");
            loadStuff(); 
        },
        success: function(){
            $("#divid").load("path/to/template.php"); //div gets filled with template
        }
    });
}
```