# waiting for first event to finish before continuing with document.ready code

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

My question is simple.

I have some configuration and loading that needs to be done before a document.ready() call.

```
// initialize ASAP so it loads super fast
soundManager.setup({
    url: 'swf/',
    onready: SMOnReadyHandler
});
```

This `onready` event handler is likely to take, say, a long time before completion.

After THIS, I want to call a `document.ready()` event listener to load the rest of my page, as so:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // code here might be dependent on the completion of 
    // soundManager.onready event handler 
});
```

How do I ensure that `$(document).ready` occurs only after the `soundManager.onready` handler has completed fully?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what does the function onready do? or is it even a function?

Comment: You may want to invent your own event to replace $(document).ready() as shown in Alxandr's answer to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135752/can-i-call-document-ready-to-re-activate-all-on-load-event-handlers

Comment: @JayHarris: `onready` holds the method assigned to it, similar to `window.onload = function() { ... }`

Comment: if you have access to that function then i think your answers are below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `deferred`:

```
var soundManagerDeferred = $.Deferred();

soundManager.setup({
    url: 'swf/',
    onready: SMOnReadyHandler
});

function SMOnReadyHandler() {
    soundManagerDeferred.resolve();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    soundManagerDeferred.done(function() {
        //init
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, I think. Do you know of any good tutorials for Deffered objects? I am not familiar with them. I think what I'm really looking for is a way to chain asynchronous callbacks so that their order of execution matters.

Comment: Try this site. Be sure to check the two links at the bottom of this page as well: http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because the browser is who determines when the DOM is ready. My suggestion is, simply remove your document.ready handler, and pass your startup function to the sound manager's `onready`. I mean, replace this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // do init stuff 
});
```

With this:

```
function initStuff() {
    // do init stuff 
}
soundManager.setup({
    url: 'swf/',
    onready: initStuff
});
```

To ensure that you don't reference any element that's not in the DOM already, add the code to the end of your html, right before `</body>`.

Comment: doesn't this defeat the whole point of starting early to load the SoundManager config? With your code, I am effectively doing `$(document).ready(function() { soundManager.setup(); });` , right?

Comment: Well, almost. It will make a difference if you have a heavy DOM. But it guarantees that document.ready stuff runs only after the sound is loaded. Jason's answer is more elegant.