# Reorder auto number column JQuery Databale after delete data successfull in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-table, datatables

i have jquery function to giving number in column datatable and delete execution from delete button. when i try delete data in table, It cannot be reorder again.
here is my issue.
[image]

It should be sorted again from 1-4. **table_id** is my id table.

Here is myHTML code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable" id="table_id">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="10px">#</th>
                <th>Bagian</th>
                <th width="90px">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Bagian</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            @if (ViewBag.JabatanList != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in ViewBag.JabatanList)
                {
                    <tr id="row_@item.JabatanId">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>@item.NamaJabatan</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("CreateEdit","Jabatan",new { Id = item.JabatanId })" class="btn bg-blue waves-effect" title="Ubah"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn bg-red waves-effect" title="Hapus" data-type="confirm" onclick="ConfirmDelete(@item.JabatanId)"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@*catch JabatanId*@
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenJabatanId" />
```

this my AJAX code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        RowNumber(); //calling row number function
    });

    var RowNumber = function () {
        var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
            //default show entries
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 75, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 75, 100, "All"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            //row number
            "columnDefs": [{
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "targets": 0
            }]
        });

        table.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
            table.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
                cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
            });
        }).draw();
    }

    var ConfirmDelete = function (JabatanId) {
        $("#hiddenJabatanId").val(JabatanId); //passing value JabatanId
    }

    var DeleteBagian = function () {

        var bgnId = $("#hiddenBagianId").val();
        //debugger
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Bagian/Delete",
            data: { Id: bgnId },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#row_" + bgnId).remove(); //after remove row that succesfull delete, will re-order auto number again
                $(document).ready(); //here i call document ready in order to reorder auto number
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

i have tried several ways to do this, i tried calling

Any suggest for this case I will appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post your all html? With the action button?

Comment: @AkshayKriti i have added for html code above

Comment: Did you tried my solution. I hope this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User your html structure as same which you have above:

For rendering the table use the below snippet:

`fnRowCallback` that is callback for when the search and delete is done.

on document ready

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function () {
    RowNumber(); //calling row number function
});
```

***Rownumber()***

```
var RowNumber = function () {

    table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
        //default show entries
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 75, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 75, 100, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        //row number
        "columnDefs": [{
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        }],
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            debugger
            var oSettings = this.fnSettings();
            $("td:first", nRow).html(oSettings._iDisplayStart + iDisplayIndex + 1);
            return nRow;
        }
    });
}
```

***DeleteBagain()***

```
var DeleteBagian = function () {
    var bgnId = $("#hiddenBagianId").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Bagian/Delete",
        data: { Id: JabatanId },
        success: function (result) {
            table.row('#row_' + bgnId).remove().draw();
        }
    });
}
```

For the error **datatable cannot reinitialise datatable**.

Change your logic to implement this after the ajax delete success.

```
success: function (result) {
           table.row('#row_' + bgnId).remove().draw();
        }
```

Will do the trick.

Please try and let me know. I hope this helps!

Comment: i have added for the html code that btnDelete I set from html, it isn't from AJAX

Comment: i added onclick event in my delete button and call it from AJAX using `ConfirmDelete()` function

Comment: it worked perfectly. just declare global variable as `table` and call it again in `DeleteBagian()`. code like your suggestion above `table.row('#row_' + bgnId).remove().draw();`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `$(document).ready()` manually; it is only run when the page loads. You can refer to [Can I call $(document).ready() to re-activate all on load event handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135752/can-i-call-document-ready-to-re-activate-all-on-load-event-handlers) for further details.

However, you should be able to call the RowNumber function within your ajax success.

```
var DeleteBagian = function () {
    var bgnId = $("#hiddenBagianId").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Bagian/Delete",
        data: { Id: bgnId },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#row_" + bgnId).remove(); //after remove row that succesfull delete, will re-order auto number again
            RowNumber();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work because i need display row auto number `$(document).ready()`.when i call `RowNumber();` function after `DeleteBagian` function it will show error **datatable cannot reinitialise datatable**